# WPF Windows Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm in planning of creating the windows Wpf application of the below image structure.

[image]

When i choose 'Class creator', In right hand side i want to load the ClassCreator.xaml and when i choose 'Text Replacer', In right hand side i want to load the TextReplace.xaml. How i can navigate in the above manner.

```
    <Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ToolMenu" Width="100">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Class Creator" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text Replacer" />
        </ListBox>
        <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1"  Name="border1" />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: There are way too many similar questions and quite a few approaches to this "problem". Do some research first and then come back with a specific problem... Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Frame` as a host to navigate contents.

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ToolMenu" Width="100">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Class Creator" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text Replacer" />
        </ListBox>
        <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1"  Name="border1">
            <Frame x:Name="frame1" Source="ClassCreator.xaml" />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Then in the ListBox's SelectionChanged event handler, navigate to another view as following

```
frame1.Navigate(new Uri("TextReplace.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

**Update: Alternatively**

The layout structure fits that of a `TabControl`. You can style a `TabControl` according to this layout, with the Tab headers on the left, and the tab items on the right.

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                                </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Header="Class Creator">
            <local:ClassCreator />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Text Replacer">
            <local:TextReplacer />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```